# Uninstall plugin from Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: aptana

How can I uninstall a plugin from Aptana Studio 3? I can't seem to find a menu option for removal. I found some search results talking about removing plugins from Aptana Studio 2 but nothing for Aptana Studio 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this as following:

Go to 'About Aptana Studio' (or simply about). On Windows this should be under 'Help'. On Mac it's the left-most menu. There you can click on Installation Details and their you can remove / change your configuration.

Comment: When I got to Installation Details, On my Plug-ins tab, there is no uninstall button. Any idea where to find it?

Comment: On the Features tab I see only next buttons License, Plig-in Details, Columns, Close

Answer (score 0):

....there is a .txt file in your Aptana installation folder called fulluninstall.txt containing info. or you can just follow this link to uninstallation wiki:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Uninstalling+Studio

Answer (score 0):

It's on the same page, where you install new software:

- Help > Install New Software
- Under the checkbox "Hide items that are
  already installed"
- There is a link "**What is already installed?**"

Press this link you can see what plugins do you actually have and manage them (update, remove..)